# Expected type 'Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]', got 'Tuple[ImgDirs, ImgDirs, ImgDirs]' instead

Tags: python

**Python 3.8.5**

```
def delete_catalogue_from_media(instance,
                                file_type: Union[general.ImgDirs.RASTER,
                                                 general.ImgDirs.SVG,
                                                 general.ImgDirs.FAV]) -> None:
    # //@formatter:off
    # Assertions {
    assert isinstance(file_type, (general.ImgDirs.RASTER, general.ImgDirs.SVG, general.ImgDirs.FAV))
    # } Assertions
    # //@formatter:on
```

**The problem**

IDE (Pycharm Community 2020.3) shows an error about type mysmatch.

```
Expected type 'Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]', got 'Tuple[ImgDirs, ImgDirs, ImgDirs]' instead 
 Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.
```

Could you help me correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm is complaining that `(general.ImgDirs.RASTER, ...)` does not comply with the expected signature of `isinstance`, which accepts tuples if made up of `Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]]`.

Said otherwise, we need more details about what is in `general.ImgDirs`: are they classes, inheritance from the `typing` module, or some composition of base types?